# Singleton or Static? Best practice For php?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, static, singleton

I built small mvc structure and I also created small basic Dependency Invoker based on Reflection class.
My question is which one is best practice for using dependent class.
For example I have class Call Request and I will use .

```
public function method(Request $request);
```

My Question is how to load Request class

1. Using Singleton and non static class var

   ```
   class Request{
   protected $var;
   }
   ```
2. Using New Instance with Static Var

   ```
   class Request{
   protected static $var;
   }
   ```

Comment: Checkout this : http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#singleton & in a general way, if Best practices make some interest for you, checkout http://www.phptherightway.com/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice between a singleton pattern and a "new instance with static" doesn't really resolves the dependency injection question.

However I suggest you to use the [singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to access your `Request` object.

**Why ?**

- This pattern fits your needs, it respects the "one and unique object instance" for your `Request` class.
- Developers should be aware of this structure, that's a proof of sustainability.
- Encapsulation
- Design patterns are 99% "best pratices"

**And the dependency injection ?**

From my experience, I suggest you to take a look at the [factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

You'll centralize the creation of your objects and the dependencies injection will be a lot easier and cleaner.

Of course, this is only my way to code, I don't pretend to have the best practices and this should be discussable.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach is neither of those.  Instead, you should pass your DC to the class constructors that need it.

Having a dependency container is loose enough as it is without going overboard using global constructs (static elements are global).